# Quick view Phone number Outlook 2007

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007, phone

In Outlook 2003 I was able to right click on a name/email address in the To/From/CC line when viewing an email and see a "Call..." entry listing phone numbers in the right-click menu.  In Outlook 2007 the "Call.." menu item is no longer there.

Is it possible to get this functionality back in Outlook 2007 or is there another way to quickly view a phone number?

I'm aware I can right click and view Outlook properties/contact info, but having the phone number one click away is convenient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you install Skype with its Outlook plugin you will recover the "Call" function for Outlook. This should also let you view the contact's phone number quickly.

Also, Outlook 2010 has updated the contacts integration and you can get an "Expanded Contact Card" straight from the To/From/CC line.

Comment: I don't like the idea of adding plugin, but I think I'll give it a try.  Thanks.